# Tensorflow wants CUDA 9 and not CUDA 10?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, tensorflow

I'm trying to use Tensorflow on Windows 10, and I have installed CUDA version 10.1 on my computer. However, after installing the AI toolbox from Visual Studio and attempting to run Tensorflow, I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 30, in <module>
    self_check.preload_check()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\self_check.py", line 82, in preload_check
    % (build_info.cudart_dll_name, build_info.cuda_version_number))
ImportError: Could not find 'cudart64_90.dll'. TensorFlow requires that this DLL be installed in a directory that is named in your %PATH% environment variable. Download and install CUDA 9.0 from this URL: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit
```

But why is it telling me to install CUDA 9, when I already have CUDA 10?

Comment: Tensorflow has very specific compatibility requirements. You might be using a version of TF that requires CUDA 9. Since we have no idea what TF version you are using, we can't say any more than that.

Comment: CUDA 10 or 10.1 cannot be used as a replacement for CUDA 9.  In general this is true of CUDA.  If an application is linked against a particular CUDA library version, you must provide that library version.  In this sense, newer CUDA toolkits cannot substitute for older ones.

Comment: That makes sense then, thanks